# Is there any way, on Chrome DevTools, to see if a property’s value was set as a result of author stylings, user-agent stylings or initial stylings

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-devtools

Is there any way, on Chrome DevTools, to see if a property’s value was set as a result of author stylings, user-agent stylings or initial stylings.

I’d like to learn about initial and user-agent stylings as I create. I know it’s possible to look up initial on MDN. I don’t actually know a document that lists all of, for example, Chrome’s stylings.

I'm guessing, if there were a way, it'd lie in the 'Styles' & 'Computed' section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the Styles tab, you can see which CSS rules are being applied, and where the rules come from. On Stack Overflow, you can see:

[image]

On the top right of a rule set section, you can see the source of the rules listed on the left. If the top right says "user agent stylesheet", then the rules for that section which are *not* crossed out are being applied. (If the rules are crossed out, they're being overridden by later rules on the page)

If the top right says `<style>` or a filename like `something.css`, then the styles are being applied due to a style tag on the page.

The screenshot above is when the `<body>` is being selected. As you can see, there are 2 user agent stylesheet rules for the body: `display: block` and `margin: 8px`. But both rules are crossed out; they're being overridden by rules in `<style>` tags on the page.

There are also initial properties which are not set in the `<style>` of a page, or by the user agent stylesheet. These can be differentiated by going to the "Computed" tab and checking which properties are faded out. For example, on an empty page with just a `<div>`, you'll see:

[image]

The only rule (here) applied by the user agent stylesheet is `display: block` on the `<div>`. All the other faded-out rules are the initial ones. Rules applied by the user agent stylesheet or by a `<style>` tag will be dark red and black, not faded.

Comment: Thanks @CertainPerformance. I assumed the properties listed in 'Computed' were also properties being applied to the selected element. If so, that would make this list in 'Styles' non-exhaustive. It looks like the highlighted properties in 'Computed' display in 'Styles'. Why are certain properties highlighted in 'Computed'? Granted, there is probably some doc on ChromeDevTools - any resources you could pass on would be appreciated

Comment: If you have highlighted properties in Styles, you probably entered something in the search box at the top. Eg, if you put in `display`, properties with `display` will be highlighted (and only rules which contain `display` will be shown).

Comment: Seen your update - thanks a bunch. If you know of any documentation that would've shown me this answer, would you mind pointing it out to me?

Comment: The CSS Reference page mentions a bunch of related things: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/css/reference

Comment: I've noticed, for instance in `body`, if you look at its `height` in the Computed section even though it's being applied initial styling (`auto`) - `height` will **not** be grey and will show its 'actual' value e.g. `50px`. How can I make my understanding of greyed-out features here more accurate?